# How to make paypal hosted button using paypal api

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

are to create paypal hosted button for my products. i must create one for every product i have in paypal site. and there any way to  create hosted button that change according to the product Moreover to be secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [Button Manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/).

If you're working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls to get this done very simple for you.

If you happen to be using WordPress specifically then I would take a look at this [PayPal WP Button Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-wp-button-manager/) which will allow you to create hosted buttons from within WP.

If you're using something besides PHP you can just make the API calls directly using any language you prefer based on the documentation I provided above.  Specifically, [BMCreateButton](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/).

Comment: thanks.bro- moreover can u specify difference between buy now button and pay now button and for creating pay now button . create it only form **BMCreateButton**.

Comment: BMCreateButton has a BUTTONTYPE parameter where you would specify the type of button you're creating.  I do not see a "PAYNOW" value there.  Only "BUYNOW" so wherever you're seeing that I think it's referring to the same thing.